# Does jq have a filepath length limit?

Tags: windows, jq, pathname

(OS is Windows 7 Professional. jq is version 1.5.)

I've been using jq to automate prettifying some JSON files (with Python). It seems to me after some time trying to determine why it wasn't working that jq fails silently when working with a file path string that's length 28, or simply stops working if the file path string is length 29 or more.

E.g. on `cmd` (and it's worth pointing out that I made a kind of shortcut so that `jq` calls `jq-win64.exe`, and tested the latter directly as well, so that's not the source of the issue):

```
C:\jq>jq . 123456789012345678901234567
```

displays prettified content of the file;

```
C:\jq>jq . 1234567890123456789012345678
```

displays nothing; and

```
C:\jq>jq . 12345678901234567890123456789
```

causes a "jq-win64.exe has stopped working" window.

(I also tested this on JSON files within folders; the common point was that the input string be of length 28 or more including slashes to fail.)

Is this a bug? If it's not, <strike>what can I do to work around it</strike> Okay, I admit that was a stupid question, I can work around it by copying content into a temp file in the base folder, prettify it, and then save it back to wherever I want it to be. More on-point question: is this the best workaround available for me to take?

Comment: Fortunately it can be worked around by piping your input into jq instead. It's just the way the input files are opened that's causing the problem in Windows.

Comment: @JeffMercado - thanks, I like that solution more than what I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

There was a Windows-specific bug in jq 1.5 (see e.g. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1094).  It was fixed shortly after the release of jq 1.5.

To obtain a post-1.5 .exe for Windows, see any of:

- https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=jq
- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download
- https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#windows-using-appveyor

Comment: Thanks for the input. Personally, I would prefer to use a "official" release, but I did at least test out a post-1.5 version and confirmed that it works